# Column already exist error while adding a unique column to a table in Laravel migration

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel

Good day. Please I ran into this error in my laravel app. I have a table of product. I want to add a 'url' column that will be unique. After running the migration, I get the error below. Please what is the way out of this? Thanks in anticipation.

```
Migrating: 2020_02_03_184424_add_url_to_products

   Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[42S21]: Column already exists: 1060 Duplicate column name 'url' (SQL: alter table `products` add `url` varchar(255) not null)

  at C:\xampp\htdocs\alvinsmakeup\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:665
    661|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    662|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    663|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    664|         catch (Exception $e) {
  > 665|             throw new QueryException(
    666|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    667|             );
    668|         }
    669|

  Exception trace:

  1   PDOException::("SQLSTATE[42S21]: Column already exists: 1060 Duplicate column name 'url'")
      C:\xampp\htdocs\alvinsmakeup\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:459

  2   PDOStatement::execute()
      C:\xampp\htdocs\alvinsmakeup\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:459

  Please use the argument -v to see more details.

Process finished with exit code 1 at 18:50:21.
Execution time: 1,796 ms.
```

This is my table schema

```
class AddUrlToProducts extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            //
            $table->string('url')->unique();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            //
            $table->dropColumn('url');
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show your migration and your current table schema.

Comment: Can you verify if that column already exists on database?. Do you have more migrations to do after that one?.

Comment: You've only shown the migration, not the current table schema.

Comment: 1. You should define a default value or set field nullable
2. Check your db, most likely you've already added 'url' column, but there was a error with 1 or unique index and record to migrations table wasn't added.

Comment: Did you get this issue solved?

Answer (score 0):

The column probably exists in your table. You can try to rollback the migration by running:

```
php artisan migrate:rollback
```

If the column does not disappear from your table. Delete it manually and rerun the migration by using:

```
php artisan migrate
```

Answer (score 0):

Either you can check if the column is already exists and drop it before adding it or add it only when it is not available.

```
 if (! Schema::hasColumn('products', 'url')) {
           Schema::table('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            //
            $table->string('url')->unique();
        });
  }
```

OR

```
 if (Schema::hasColumn('products', 'url')) {
       Schema::table('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->drop('url');
        });
  }

  Schema::table('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            //
       $table->string('url')->unique();
  });
```

Or if you have added this column in last migration, just rollbalck, make changes and run migration command again.